# Spark Optimisation Not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a different set of SQL operations in pySpark. However, the optimization is not happening as expected.
Ideally, spark optimizes the whole execution plan before doing the actual thing.

Logic written is as below -

```
df = spark.read.csv("s3://data/")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
df2=spark.sql("select * from data where p_report_date=20200901")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("data2")
df3=spark.sql("select * from data2")
df3.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("s3_path_2")
```

Data files are stored with partitions -

```
s3://data/p_report_date=20200901,
s3://data/p_report_date=20200902
s3://data/p_report_date=20200903
```

So basically the action is called in df3, before that all is just transformations.
I am assuming spark to read only the folder which is mentioned in the where clause in df2(s3://data/p_report_date=20200901). But it's reading all the partitions in s3://data first & then filtering the p_report_date.

We are using EMR6.5.0 & Spark-3.1.2

**Question - Why is spark not optimizing the query to read only the mentioned folder first in place of reading everything??**

Comment: What is the issue here, lack of optimization (all partitions are being read even that only the data of one partition is being written) or allegedly wrong results (the filter doesn't seem to be applied)?. In any case, please add the execution plan

Comment: The first one is the issue - reading all the partitions even though only one partition needs to be filtered.

Comment: Obviously Spark identifies the folder as partitions, otherwise the use of column `p_report_date` would have been invalid (or you have column with that name in your data files and then the issue is clear). What makes you think that Spark reads the data files in all folders?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Yes, we have a column with the name - p_report_date in our data. You can check the query for df2, we need to read only one date. Not all.

Comment: If you have such a column in your data files, and it's not taken from the folder names, how exactly do you expect to filter the data without reading the data files?

Comment: we have 554 p_report_date folders on S3.  Each of these folders has 1 file with a size of around 100  KB. While a job is running, it takes more than 1 hour and then fails with error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.  In Spark UI, I see that the first step has created 554 tasks and they take all the time before the job fails in EMR.
We have 5 worker nodes with 16GB RAM and 4 Vcores

Comment: (1) Nothing here make sense. You don't use header=True. and you don't supply schema. That means that Spark is using the default columns names _c0, _c1 etc. and that `p_report_date` is coming from the folders names and not from the data files. (2) Defining partitions over small volumes of data is bad practice.